# Create a structure array from a list in Numpy with string and integers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've read through the documentation but cannot work out how to create a structured array of strings and integers with numpy. A shortened version of my problem is below:

```
foo = [['asd', 1, 2],['bgf',2,3]]
bar = np.array(foo, dtype=['S10', 'i4','i4'])
```

I would then like to have `bar[:,0]` as an array of strings and `bar[:,1]`and `bar[:,2]` as arrays of integers.

Unfortunately this gives a `TypeError: data type not understood`. I've tried many other ways to get it to work but cannot find anything intuitive.

Currently I am just doing `bar = np.array(foo)` and then casting to integer whenever I call a value from the 2nd or 3rd column, which is far from ideal.

How can I create the structure array `bar` that I would like from the list of lists `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to create the [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html):

```
>>> foo = [('asd', 1, 2),('bgf',2,3)]
>>> bar = np.array(foo, dtype='S10,i4,i4')
>>> bar
array([('asd', 1, 2), ('bgf', 2, 3)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S10'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
>>> bar['f0']
array(['asd', 'bgf'], 
      dtype='|S10')
>>> bar['f1']
array([1, 2], dtype=int32)
>>> bar['f2']
array([2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

If you want a normal array, with elements rather than fields, then use `dtype=object`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one datatype in an array, use **dtype=object**.

```
>>> bar = np.array(foo, dtype=object)
>>> bar[:,0]
array(['asd', 'bgf'], dtype=object)
>>> bar[:,1]
array([1, 2], dtype=object)
>>> bar[:,2]
array([2, 3], dtype=object)
```